# How to calculate an equation in a string, python

Tags: python, string, equation

I have a variable that is `function = '(2*1)+3'`. How would I get it out of string form and calculate the answer? I tried using `float()`, `int(float())` but I'm not sure if that's for numbers only or not.

Comment: You can either use `eval` as Avinash suggested or write [your own parser](http://alfasin.com/2015/08/05/a-simple-calculator-in-python/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the parser in that link is going to be really unintelligent.  It knows nothing of parenthesis for example :-).  I've done this a few times using an `ast.NodeVisitor`, but every time I do it, I lose the code.  I should keep it around sometime -- Just for fun.

Answer (score 16):

I've written this a couple times, and every time it seems that I lose the code...

A very simple (and "safe") calculator can be created using `ast`:

```
import ast
import operator

_OP_MAP = {
    ast.Add: operator.add,
    ast.Sub: operator.sub,
    ast.Mult: operator.mul,
    ast.Div: operator.div,
    ast.Invert: operator.neg,
}


class Calc(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        left = self.visit(node.left)
        right = self.visit(node.right)
        return _OP_MAP[type(node.op)](left, right)

    def visit_Num(self, node):
        return node.n

    def visit_Expr(self, node):
        return self.visit(node.value)

    @classmethod
    def evaluate(cls, expression):
        tree = ast.parse(expression)
        calc = cls()
        return calc.visit(tree.body[0])


print Calc.evaluate('1 + 3 * (2 + 7)')
```

This calculator supports numbers, addition, subtraction, division, multiplication and negation (e.g. `-6`) and parenthesised groups.  Order of operations are the same as Python which should be relatively intuitive...  It can (almost trivially) be extended to support just about any unary or binary operator that python supports by adding the `ast` node type and corresponding operator/function to the `_OP_MAP` above.

Comment: This is the best python string calculator out there. There should be a link from all those others to here. I spent hours looking until I found this one.

Comment: I am working on a Linux accounting program called [PyGtk Posting](https://github.com/benreu/PyGtk-Posting), licensed under GPLv3. Could I have your permission to include this code, and license it GPLv3? Otherwise, what license do you prefer?

Comment: @theGtknerd -- If this code is going to be licensed, I'd want it to be something nice and permissive (e.g. Apache 2.0, MIT, ...).  I have no problem with you using it in your project as long as the GPL doesn't somehow magically start applying to _this_ code as well preventing it's use in other (commercial) applications.

Comment: Apache 2.0 and GPLv3 are compatible. See my [commit](https://github.com/benreu/PyGtk-Posting/commit/9a34641b62c9639599641f9965ef5ffbb752cb3a). Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You may use `eval`

```
>>> function = '(2*1)+3'
>>> eval(function)
5
```

As @mgilson said,

*Only do this if you completely trust the source of the string.*

Comment: Note, Only do this if you completely trust the source of the string :-)

Comment: function is a bad name for a string.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own GitHub repository for this: 
https://github.com/SubatomicPlanets/StrToMath  
It's just one file with about 100 lines and no third-party libraries, and it's pretty simple.
It uses the shunting yard algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm
Basically, what it's doing is getting a string like "2+4*6"(this is called infix notation) and formatting it into something called postfix notation.
The same expression in postfix looks like this: "246*+"
It is just a different way of writing it.
Calculating postfix is a lot simpler than calculating infix, because there are no parentheses.
In the file I made, I also added a lot of other stuff, like constants, so that you can do this:

### Examples:

```
"what's fifty three+7*6/2?"     -> 74
"what is 9 * 67+90?"            -> 693
"2^7"                           -> 128
"-pi+pi"                        -> 0
"-pi*two"                       -> -6.283184
"(twenty two*2)+one"            -> 45
```